Is it possible to reply to email when an item is created or modified?
I'm building a ticketing system.
My first flow: When an email comes in, it populates a list and creates an item.
My second flow: When I edit the description of the item, I want it to reply to the same email. Is this possible?
The issue I'm running into is the Message Id in the Reply to email action. I get this error:
"It seems that the error "Id is malformed" is occurring in the 'Reply to email (V3)' operation. To fix this, check the parameter references in the 'Reply to email (V3)' operation. Ensure that the 'ID', 'Issueloggedby', 'Title', and 'Description' parameters are correctly referenced from the 'triggerOutputs' output. Double-check the spelling and structure of these parameters to resolve the error."
